# How large must $n$ be if $|\sin(x) - T_n(x)| < 0.01$ for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose that $f(x) = \sin(x)$, and that $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th Taylor's polynomial of $f$ centered at $0$.

How large must $n$ be if $|f(x) - T_n(x)| < 0.01$ for all $x$ on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Hint $f(x)-T_n(x)=R_n(x)=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$.

Comment: I'm clueless...

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1. By Taylor's theorem,
   $$
   f(x)-T_n(x)=R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},
   $$
   where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$.
2. If $f(x)=\sin x$, then
   $$
   f^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}(-1)^k\cos x,&n=2k+1\\(-1)^k\sin x,&n=2k\end{cases}
   $$
   where $k\in {\mathbb Z^+}$. Moreover, you can state that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$ for all $n$.

**Edit** Extensing answer to full solution using the above hints.

From the above hints, we have
$$\left|f(x)-T_n(x)\right|=\frac{\left|f^{(n+1)}(x)\right||x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\leq\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},$$
since $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$ and $\left|x\right|\leq\pi$.

Thus, for an error less than $\tau$, we need $\dfrac{\pi^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\leq\tau$. For $\tau=0.01$, it can be calculated that $n>10.763$. Thus, to achieve the desired accuracy, it is required that $n>11$.